# XMLStarlet delete parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I'm new using XMLStarlet and I'm wondering whether there is the possibility to remove a parent node that has a child with a specific value inside his tag.

In my example, I want to remove the node "**<tabVisibilities>**" that has inside a child node "**<tab>**" with the specfic value "**SecondTab**":

Starting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>FirstTab</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>SecondTab</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>ThirdTab</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOff</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
</Profile>
```

Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>FirstTab</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>ThirdTab</tab>
        <visibility>DefaultOff</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
</Profile>
```

Thank you very much, Davide.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file uses namespaces.

```
xmlstarlet edit -N ns='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata' --delete "//ns:tabVisibilities[ns:tab[contains(text(),'SecondTab')]]" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <tabVisibilities>
    <tab>FirstTab</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
  </tabVisibilities>
  <tabVisibilities>
    <tab>ThirdTab</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOff</visibility>
  </tabVisibilities>
</Profile>
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`