# XML: how can I search in whole xml and find nodes by id and delete them?

Tags: xml, bash, xquery, xmlstarlet, basex

A simple example of a xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
    <speklap name="gj">
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="en" id="2">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
    <photostore>
        <photo>
             <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
             <price>1.000</price>
           </photo>
       </photostore>
    </speklap>
 </bookstore>
```

What I want to achieve is to search for a node with attributes id =2 and id=3 and remove the only this 2 nodes. The problem is that I can found enough examples by targeting the node but not how to search the whole xml and find a node based on a id and remove only the node with this id.

So the desired output is:

```
<bookstore>
    <speklap name="gj">
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
    <photostore>
        <photo>
             <price>1.000</price>
           </photo>
       </photostore>
    </speklap>
 </bookstore>
```

It would be great to make a simple script but I'm a beginner. I tried XQuery. But im also interested in a bash script. Hope somebody can help me in the good direction

Comment: Which XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: Im using basex 9.5

Comment: This might help: [XMLStarlet delete parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66697357/3776858)

Comment: Thx Cyrus I managed to fix it with xml starlet but only for one id: Do you know how to add the second id?

xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[@id='1']" test.xml

Comment: `xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[@id='1']" -d "//*[@id='2']" test.xml`?

Comment: Thnx Cyrus I just found also this working example:
xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[@id='1'or @id='2']" test.xml

Comment: With XSLT this is extremely easy. Are you interested in an XSLT solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With BaseX, the following command call can be used to delete nodes in a document:

```
basex -u -i test.xml "delete node //*[@id = (2, 3)]"
```

With `-u`, updates will be propagated back to the original file. With `-i`, the input document is specified. The subsequent string is a valid XQuery expression with the requested update.

One alternative is to directly specify the input document in the query (and I have slightly modified the predicate; it’s equivalent to the first version):

```
basex -u "delete node doc('test.xml')//*[@id = 2 or @id = 3]"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[@id='1'or @id='2']" test.xml
```

Comment: This would also be possible if you need a range. `xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[@id>'0' and  @id<'3']" test.xml`

Comment: Great answer. If you added a little explanation I would upvote it.