# Linux script to extract XML parent tags having certain values in one of its child tag

Tags: linux, xml, awk, extract

I have an XML with the following format

```
<SaleEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>111</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</SaleEvent>
<SaleEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>123</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</SaleEvent>
<SaleEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>456</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</SaleEvent>
<RefundEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>789</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</RefundEvent>
```

I want to extract the whole **SaleEvent/RefundEvent** tag (along with its children tag), which having **ReceiptId** 123, 789 (*The ReceiptId is one of its child, and I have the list of ReceiptId to extract*).

I have tried with the following awk command:

```
for k in `grep -v -F -x -f $file1.csv $file2.csv`
do
   awk -v pattern="$k" 'BEGIN {RS="<SaleEvent" ;FS="<"} $0 ~ pattern && ($NF == "/SaleEvent>") {print RS $0}' $input.xml >>  $output.xml
done
```

That command will get list of ReceiptId that is in file2.csv but not in file1.csv then store in k. Then for each of k, try to extract ReceiptId stored in $k from $input.xml to $output.xml
But still it does not work for some Receipt, which I don't know why.

Is there something missing in that command that still some Receipts are still not extracted? Is there another command to be used for this purpose?

The actual input XML file is **minimized** version, so everything is in 1 line. Something like

```
<SaleEvent><Extention><ReceiptId>111</ReceiptId></Extention></SaleEvent<SaleEvent><Extention><ReceiptId>123</ReceiptId></Extention></SaleEvent> ...
```

The expected output is (*it doesn't have to be in beautified version, just for sake of readability*)

```
<SaleEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>123</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</SaleEvent>
<RefundEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>789</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</RefundEvent>
```

*Btw, I run the script in cygwin for windows*

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: This might help: [XMLStarlet delete parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66697357/3776858)

Comment: Please provide a well-formed example xml file.

Comment: Please add the exact expected output for your posted sample input.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this solution (refined and improved with help from Ed Morton, cf. comment below), which will work with any awk:

```
awk '/<(Sale|Refund)Event>/{f=1} f{i=i $0 ORS} /<\/(Sale|Refund)Event>/{if(i ~ /<ReceiptId>(789|123)<\//){printf "%s", i} i=f=""}' input.xml
```

**Output**

```
<SaleEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>123</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</SaleEvent>
<RefundEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>789</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</RefundEvent>
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '
/<(Sale|Refund)Event>/ {             # When XML start tags match 
  f=1}                               # set f to true
f { i=i $0 ORS}                      # With f true collect lines and output record separator
/<\/(Sale|Refund)Event>/ {           # When XML end tags match
  if(i ~ /<ReceiptId>(789|123)<\//){ # if ReceiptId satifies condition ..
    printf "%s", i                   # print lines
  } 
  i=f=""                             # unset i
}' input.xml
```

**Update** with a minified XML and dynamic variables

```
BEGIN { rec_id ="<ReceiptId>"var"</" # Construct regexp with variable to match later
  }
/<(Sale|Refund)Event>/ {             # When XML start tags match 
  f=1}                               # set f to true
f { i=i $0 ORS}                      # With f true collect lines and output record separator
/<\/(Sale|Refund)Event>/ {           # When XML end tags match
  if(match(i, rec_id)){              # if rec_id matches
    printf "%s", i                   # print lines
  } 
  i=f=""                             # unset i
}
```

To deal with minified XML run it through a tool like `tidy` along these lines:

`tidy -iq -xml input.xml | awk -v var="$k" -f tst.awk`

Comment: `<(SaleEvent|RefundEvent)>` could be appreviated to `<(Sale|Refund)Event>` (and same for `/<\/.../`) and more importantly `/<ReceiptId>(789|123)/` needs to be anchored as `/<ReceiptId>(789|123)</` or it'll falsely match `<ReceiptId>123456`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It works if the input is in beautified version as in the example (sorry for missing to explain this before) and actually I have a loop in my script to store the dynamic ReceiptId in k (I have edited my main question to explain these 2 things).

So, there are 2 questions:
1. What if the input file is in minimized version (everything is in 1 line)?
2. How to incorporate a dynamic ReceiptId? As in my edited main question, I have a loop to store the dynamic ReceiptId to be extracted in a variable k.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is always structured exactly as you show then with GNU awk for mult-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='</(Sale|Refund)Event>[[:blank:]]*\n' -v ORS= '/<ReceiptId>(123|789)</{print $0 RT}' file
<SaleEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>123</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</SaleEvent>
<RefundEvent>
    ...
    <Extention>
        <ReceiptId>789</ReceiptId>
        ...
    </Extention>
    ...
</RefundEvent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go python, something like (calling your doc doc.xml)
install lxml, you need

```
import pathlib
from lxml import etree
# I put an <all></all> around the file
doc = etree.fromstring(b'<all>'+pathlib.Path("doc.xml").read_bytes()+b'</all>')

# then find things
parents=[]
for i in doc.xpath('//*[text()="123"]'): 
    parents.append(list(i.iterancestors())[-2])
print(parents)
```

When You want to write the 'parents' back to a file, You can (I did) find help here:

http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/python/lxml.htm#writing_an_xhtml_to_epub_converter_program